# terraform throw error: "Incorrect attribute value type" when I run plan

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I using terraform from https://github.com/Oxalide/terraform-fargate-example.

When I run as it is I get error:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on main.tf line, in resource "aws_alb" "main":
  :   subnets         = ["${aws_subnet.public.*.id}"]

Inappropriate value for attribute "subnets": element 0: string required.
```

The code in this line:

```
resource "aws_alb" "main" {
  name            = "tf-ecs-chat"
  subnets         = ["${aws_subnet.public.*.id}"] # <--- here is the error
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.lb.id}"]
}
```

[According to the docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lb.html) example it seems right.

```
resource "aws_lb" "test" {
  name               = "test-lb-tf"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = ["${aws_security_group.lb_sg.id}"]
  subnets            = ["${aws_subnet.public.*.id}"]
  ...
```

What the error means? how to solve it?

Comment: That example is 3 years old and TF has changed a lot since then

Comment: Which version of terraform are you using?

Comment: v0.12.18, but I'll update to the last version. I using this repo to do ecs with fargate.

Comment: You are using an old syntax of terraform that changed with 0.12.x.
Why you don't enumerate all subnet? like this :
[aws_subnet.public.sub1.id, aws_subnet.public.sub2.id]

Comment: This does look a lot like an error related to unsupported former syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This example seems to have been written for an older version of Terraform and is, unfortunately, relying on a configuration language bug from that earlier version that has since been fixed.

The expression `aws_subnet.public.*.id` produces a list of the `id` attribute values from all of the instances of `aws_subnet.public`. If you put that expression inside the list construction brackets `[` `]` then Terraform understands that as a list of lists, like this:

```
[
  [
    "i-abc123",
    "i-def456",
    "i-ghi789",
  ],
]
```

The `aws_alb` resource type then rejects that as a value for `subnets`, because that argument is defined as expecting a list of strings, not a list of lists of strings.

Because `aws_subnet.public.*.id` already returns a list, you can just use it directly as the value of `subnets`:

```
  subnets         = aws_subnet.public.*.id
```

Notice also that we don't need the string interpolation syntax, because we're just using a list value directly, not constructing a string from a template.

The `security_groups` argument in your example uses similar syntax, but in that case `aws_security_group.lb.id` is already a single ID string rather than a list, and so the `[` `]` list brackets to construct a list *are* needed in that case. However, we can still clean that up by removing the unnecessary template interpolation syntax, giving the following result:

```
resource "aws_alb" "main" {
  name            = "tf-ecs-chat"
  subnets         = aws_subnet.public.*.id
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.lb.id]
}
```

---

Some of the examples in the Terraform provider documentation are still using syntax from older versions of Terraform, particularly in situations where the provider in question is still compatible with the older version, which I believe is the case for the AWS provider at the time I'm writing this.

In most cases that just results in unnecessarily-verbose syntax, but there are unfortunately some cases like this where the example was relying on a bug in the former version that has now been fixed, and so the example itself no longer works correctly in current Terraform versions.

If you notice cases like this, you can report a bug by following the "Report an Issue" link on the provider's page in the Terraform Registry. In this case, the provider in question is [`hashicorp/aws`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws).